# Restricting SQL Server Management Studio using LogMeIn Hamachi

Tags: security, sql-server, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-network

I have a SQL Server 2016 instance on Windows Service 2012 VM running in Azure.
Currently the network security group/firewall allows for port 1433/TCP traffic so I can connect from my PC using SQL Server Management studio.

However, I don't want that anyone on the internet that can guess my SQL username can access the VM/Databases.

I now have Hamachi installed on my VM's to create a virtual network, but what do I have to change to only allow users within the virtual hamachi network to access SQLServer Management studio?

Comment: Block with the windows firewall traffic coming to the port 1433 from the internet ?

Comment: Your NSG should be configured to allow connections only from the ip addresses you specify. If so, then only those hosts can access the database.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed that the azure firewall took some time to manifest its changes even after it said 'done'. I've blocked port 1433 now and when using the ipv4 address hamachi gives me I can still connect using SMSS.